# Setting dynamic version for swagger API version

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to make version dynamic in below annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Test APIs", version = "${project.version}", description = "Testing APIs"))
public class DemoApplication {

}
```

Here I want to make version dynamic so it will take value from pom.xml file.

Do I need to have any configuration for that?
TIA.

Comment: You can put the version in application.properties and access it directly. Otherwise [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-accessing-maven-properties) article on reading maven properties inside java project might be helpful. But do keep in mind swagger is meant for contract first API development and creating docs & API interfaces from specs is the way to do that.

Comment: "swagger is meant for contract first API development" I beg to disagree, swagger is meant as a way to standardize the description of an API, it does not imply contract-first.

Comment: what library do I need to import for OpenAPIDefinition class

Comment: @guilhermecgs I am importing https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

Answer (score 6):

You can define the OpenAPIDefinition programatically and use the BuildProperties to set OpenAPIDefinition.info data like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    @Autowired
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components())
            .info(new Info()
                .title(buildProperties.getArtifact() + " API")
                .version(buildProperties.getVersion())
                .description(buildProperties.getArtifact() + " - API Swagger documentation")
                .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")));
    }
}
```

You'll need add the 'build-info' goal in the 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' into pom.xml file in order to use de BuildProperties component in your code:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I knew it existed and I have been looking for that a long time. Where is that documented?